# How to combine multiple excel work sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple sheets in my file which I wish to essentially paste onto the bottom of each other.

They all have the same headings:
[image]

I have tried to use the combine function, but I don't want to use any of the functions it gives me, (like sum) I simply just want to have them all pasted together into one long list.

All of the sheets have the same headings, but some have different amount of rows. I have 55 sheets, which have anything from 50-400 rows, so I don't want to copy and paste manually.

My sheets are called "Avg Route Data", "Avg Route Data (2)" and so on, all the way up until "Avg Route Data (55)"

Please can someone help.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm not trying to consolidate the data, I'm simply trying to paste it all together into a long list. I do not want my data to change, group or sum together with any functions?

Comment: Sorry that's blocked on my machine and I googled it instead - my excel doesn't recognise vstack function. How do you suggest I use the consolidate feature without it all summing together please? Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to follow this, but I can't even get the table from the first step that says got to blank query and type =Excel.CurrentWorkbook() https://trumpexcel.com/combine-multiple-worksheets/

My error: 
Expression.Error: We couldn't find an Excel table named ''Avg Raw Route Data'!_FilterDatabase'.
Details:
    'Avg Raw Route Data'!_FilterDatabase

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work as a have a different amount of rows in each of my tables, so I can't apply the same range to each sheet in the macro. Sorry

Comment: Instead of creating tables, you can just leave the source file closed. Create a new excel file, get data from the source workbook, and that way you can just get data from the sheets without creating tables.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you. That's exactly what I have done over the weekend, using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRnXAz4KaYM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRnXAz4KaYM
This is how you stack multiple tabs of the same structure of data into one long list on one sheet.